How to configure p-menubar from PrimeNG to expand from right to left for responsive version
How do I set the CSS styles, or configure the p-menubar from PrimeNg to make it expand from right to left in the responsive version because in the current version when using the classes align-items-center flex justify-content-between the menu sticks to the right edge, and "tries" to expand to the right side.
<div class="header-container align-items-center flex justify-content-between">
  <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="Image" height="40">
  <p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>
</div>


I tried many solutions based on different setting in css right, top, position, flex but everything finally looked lopsided :(

Could you try the below CSS. Same thing you did, but I set panel as absolute and positioned it to be right to left, also using width: fit-content we are able to maintain the full width!
.right-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
  position: relative;
}

.right-menu-panel ul[role='menu'].p-menubar-root-list {
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: 0px;
  top: 102%;
}

Stackblitz Demo
